# Escape String equal special characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, escaping, urlencode

I have a string in JavaScript:

```
ghi chú đặc biệt (!@#$%^&*) ngày 06/11/2018
```

> How can I escape this and parse in URL 
>   Decode this in Java? 
>   I try using:

```
encodeURIComponent(url);
```

But I just get this String:  ghi chú đặc biệt (!@
How can I fix it 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Should be straightforward

```js
var uri = "ghi chú đặc biệt (!@#$%^&*) ngày 06/11/2018";
var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
console.log (res)
```

Refer - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_encodeuricomponent

Comment: Seems OP already tried this though it's not clear why it doesn't work for them

Answer (score 0):

You can use encodeURIComponent() and decodeURIComponent() to encode and then decode a url;

```js
var url="ghi chú đặc biệt (!@#$%^&*) ngày 06/11/2018";
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(url);
var decoded = decodeURIComponent(encoded)
console.log(`Encoded url ${encoded}`);
console.log(`Decoded url ${decoded}`);
```